# Column alias for VALUES ( ) syntax

Tags: sql, db2, derby

Here's some SQL:

```
select T.*
FROM (
values ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Casual shirt ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Casual shirt-White-Small ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Casual shirt-Blue-Medium ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Cords ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Bodysuit ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Cords-Black-29W x 28L ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Bodysuit-Black-Petit ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Cords-Brown-29W x 28L ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Classic pleated dress pant ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Classic pleated dress pant-Black-29W x 32L ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Dress shirt ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Dress shirt-White-15 ' ) , ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Dress shirt-White-16 ' )
) T
;
```

It returns columns "1" and "2". How to change it so it returns named columns? Is it possible without using sysdummy1 ?

Comment: You could also use a common table expression (at least with DB2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the column names to `T`:

```
select T.*
FROM (values ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Casual shirt ' ) ,
             ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Casual shirt-White-Small ' ) ,
             ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Casual shirt-Blue-Medium ' ) ,
             ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Cords ' ) ,
             ( '2014-05-30 17:26:32.749' , 'Bodysuit ' ) ,
             . . .
     ) T(col1, col2);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about DB2 LUW, but for DB2 for i at least, if you want the first column to be returned as a timestamp, you'll need to explicitly convert it using TIMESTAMP() or CAST().  It may be enough to explicitly convert the first row.  DB2 will implicitly convert the rest.

Comment: @Charles . . . That would be true in any database.  A string constant is just that . . . a string constant.

Comment: true enough.  Except DB2 will implicitly convert string constants to date/time values where it knows it needs to.  My point is that in this case it doesn't know it needs to.